# Centos ssh require -i to connect

Tags: centos, ssh

I am currently trying to access to a remote host (let's say node1) using ssh from another (master).
As ssh-copy-id did not work I did the thing manually.

I generated a key-pair (without password) with ssh-key-gen on my local machine.
Then I uploaded the the private key on my remote master (created `~/.ssh/id_rsa`)

Then I went to my node1 and added the public key in the authorized_key

So I was able to connect to node1 from master by typing
 `ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa user@node1`

However I would like to be able to connect just by typing  `ssh user@node1`
 but I am getting error

`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`.

I think this error is coming from the fact that I am not using the key.

How can I do this?

PS: In fact this part of a script to autoconfigure access from the master to the node1 because I will install Openshift and it needs to access to node with ssh to configure it. But Issh private key is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ~/.ssh/config file. Here is an example

```
Host node1
    User <user>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Once this is configured, all you need to do is `ssh node1` going forward.

You are most likely getting that error because of the command missing the key. You can verify that by going to your /var/log/secure on the node1 server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add <path>/id_rsa
```